# MAX number of scanning computers

Tags: c#, multithreading, active-directory

I have a domain with run Active Directory equipment. I get all computers from the domain and connect to each computer in new thread. But max number of threads doesn't exceed 100. So what is the max number of threads and the max number of machines that can be scanned at one time?

**EDIT:**

```
 var scanningThreads = new Thread[scannThreads + 1];
                for (int i = 0; i < scannThreads; i++)
                {
                    scanningThreads[i] = new Thread(ShowMembersOfAdministratorsGroup) {IsBackground = true};
                    scanningThreads[i].Start(new ParametersWrapper()
                                                 { Computers = computers.GetRange(0, scanningComputers), Event = e });
                    computers.RemoveRange(0, scanningComputers);
                }
```

Comment: Are you creating your own Threads, or using the thread pool?

Comment: Can you show a sample of the code that creates a thread?

Comment: Yes. I have added a snip of code.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the max number of threads?

The answer is: a lot! Certainly more than 100. One of the limiting factors is memory - each .NET thread allocates a 1MB stack.

You never want to get close to that number in one application. Ideally, you would have the same number of threads as cores and no blocking calls. This is because threads are big resources and also becuase it takes a long ( to a CPU ) time to perform a context switch when the OS schedules a thread to run.

Ideally, you would rethink your design and use asynchronous methods and continuations running on the thread pool. Is there an asynchronous equivalent to the blocking call in  `ShowMembersOfAdministratorsGroup`? Then you wouldn't have to create so many threads that just   block on network I/O.

Comment: No, there isn't. I use WMI in this method: `var connection = new ConnectionOptions();
                ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + targethost + "\\root\\cimv2", connection);
                scope.Connect();`